# Two sets : open or not open?

Tags: general-topology

I am given two sets  : 
$$A=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 : \mid x \mid < 1, \mid y \mid \leq 1\} $$
$$B=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 : 0<x\leq 1 \}$$

I have to determine if these two sets are open or not. Can i say that : 
$$\overset{\circ}{A}=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 : \mid x \mid < 1, \mid y \mid < 1\} $$
$$\overset{\circ}{B}=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2 : 0<x < 1 \}$$
Then, these two sets are not open ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are the interiors of the sets $A$ and $B$. Therefore, none of them is open.

Comment: Okay, thank you José

Answer (score 2):

Give explicit points that are not interior points, like $(\frac12,1)$ for $A$ and $(1,0)$ for $B$, show that any open ball around those points sticks out of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What you say is exact. However, as those are quite basic questions, I would suggest that you explain how you derived the values of $\overset{\circ}{A}, \overset{\circ}{B}$.